# Bandwith Speed Boost Tips for PHP5 Servers: Output and Zlib Compression

Tags: php, performance, zlib

I have some detailed, specialist questions about the nature of the settings that go in htaccess when setting up **PHP bandwith savings** and the **effective speed gain experienced**:

Allow me to thank you in advance for your answer and clarifications on this matter as I dont understand the *encyclopedic style long-page apache manuals*

Example below is what is actually running on my Apache 2.0 and PHP 5.2.3

```
# preserve bandwidth for PHP enabled servers
<ifmodule mod_php4.c>
    php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
</ifmodule>
```

.

**Q1:** Does `ifmodule mod_php4.c` suggest that its for PHP 4 and not PHP5?

**Q2:** Would it be faster for the server engine to have this in `php.ini`, instead of htaccess?

**Q3:** The compression is default set to `16386`. What happens if we lower it to, say, `4K`

**Q4:** What would happen if we set it higher, e.g. `128K` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Q1: Does ifmodule mod_php4.c suggest that its for PHP 4 and not PHP5?

Yes.  **RUN**.  PHP4 has no reason to still be installed unless you have scripts that will break under PHP5.

> Q2: Would it be faster for the server engine to have this in php.ini, instead of htaccess?

It shouldn't matter one iota except for a few opcodes during Apache startup.  Meaning, no... unless the .htaccess file was not already present, in which case there may be a tiny performance hit as Apache finds the file.  (Fewer .htaccess files => less needless `stat` calls => faster performance for *everything*.)

> Q3: The compression is default set to 16386. What happens if we lower it to, say, 4K

[This is the size of the buffer for the output](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression).  If you drop it to 4k, data will be sent slightly sooner.  Depending on the average size of the page, this can mean that data could need to be sent in multiple chunks, which may well be a very tiny performance drop for the user getting the data.

> Q4: What would happen if we set it higher, e.g. 128K ?

This means that 128k of buffering woudl happen before data was sent to the client.  If your pages are over 128k post-gzipping, something's *probably wrong*.

> setting up PHP bandwith savings and the effective speed gain experienced:

A while ago, people started recommending *not* using PHP's built-in gzip, suggesting [Apache's mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) instead.  This lets PHP just care about generating the HTML, and lets Apache worry about compressing and serving it.  It also has the same effect.  While the manual page for mod_deflate is encyclopedic, it's also simple and straightforward.  You may already have it available and simply have the required lines unused in your httpd.conf.

Because it can operate at the "filter" level, using it also means that *anything* producing the compressed MIME types, including CGI scripts and plain old HTML files can get gzipped automatically.

---

Update with answers to comments:

> Do I read on & inbetween the lines correctly that you suggest me to remove the block A and have only block B in [place as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412681/speeding-up-websites-via-simple-apache-settings-in-htaccess-zlib-output-compress)

This is generally correct, though the configuration block you have there is currently targeting files by extension.  Instead, you can target by MIME type using the `AddOutputFilterByType` configuration directive, as documented on the mod_deflate manual.

When removing the PHP configuration, also inspect the php.ini on your system, as it may *also* contain compression directives that you might not need.

Apache will be smart enough not to double-gzip content, no matter what method you use to turn on mod_deflate.

> what would be the proper way to change the block A to make it most compatible with PHP5?

It depends on what the 5.x version of mod_php is called on your system.  It'll be either just plain old regular mod_php or mod_php5.  Look for the `LoadModule` directive elsewhere in httpd.conf (or in /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf).

The *actual configuration directive* is correct, it's just wrapped in a "do this only if PHP4 is loaded" block.

Let's say that your 5.x mod_php is called `mod_not_butter`.  If this is the case, the block would look like:

```
<IfModule mod_not_butter.c>
    php_value suckitude_factor -1
</IfModule>
```

> I wonder what other options I might have to customize/speed up my mod_deflate APACHE gzip processing

There are lots of options.  Don't touch *any* of them except the buffer size ([`DeflateBufferSize`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html#deflatebuffersize)), which you should set to the average *uncompressed* data size that you expect.  (I earlier misremembered that the buffer was after compression, while it's actually before.)

All of the other options are sane defaults that you don't need to touch, because by the time that changing them would actually impact performance in a meaningful way, you'll want to have other technologies involved to take load off Apache.

Comment: +1 for your awesome answer @Charles. Please allow some huge gap inbetween your knowledge/experience and mine. two questions for now: 1) Do I read on & inbetween the lines correctly that you suggest me to remove the block A and have only block B in place as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412681/speeding-up-websites-via-simple-apache-settings-in-htaccess-zlib-output-compress

Comment: second question would be, what would be the proper way to change the block A to make it most compatible with PHP5?  just by changing the number `4` to nr `5`?  After that, I will run some side by side comparisons. PS my pages are about 40kb html ungzipped, and after gzipping about 9 kb (75% savings is very common in my site).

Comment: Intrigued by by your answer suggesting to *`let PHP to generate HTML`* I wonder what other options I might have to customize/speed up my mod_deflate APACHE gzip processing... Thanks very much @Charles